# running knife gives me double @ at the address part

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I don't know what is wrong with my settting:

```
siegfried@ubuntu:~/chef-repo$ knife ssh -a ipaddress 'name:chefnode' 'uptime'        

WARNING: Failed to connect to  -- Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication       failed for user siegfried@192.168.1.73@192.168.1.73

failed for user siegfried@192.168.1.73@192.168.1.73
```

There is a double `@` in it. I totally have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Would probably be good to send a bug report / PR to Chef Lol ... 2 years on this is still sending people into rabbit holes (eg. Me) ...

Answer (score 6):

Not yet 100% sure what is going on but I believe the double "@" is just a print message (it is not actually trying to connect to that host).  The double comes from:

```
# net-ssh-multi-1.2.0/lib/net/ssh/multi/server.rb
#
192       rescue Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed => error
193         raise Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed.new("#{error.message}@dude#{host}")
194       end
```

I have so cleverly added the word "**dude**" here which we can see in my output:

```
user@ubuntu:~/chef-repo$ knife ssh 'name:ep1' uptime
WARNING: Failed to connect to ep1.site.com -- Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user user@ep1.site.com@dudeep1.site.com
```

Seems like some type of a bug but not our problem.  I'm going to keep debugging but probably something along the lines of @Carolyn's suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/a/22439127/851145.

**Update**

Indeed the double "@" was a complete red herring.  For me the solution was to simply specify the password with --ssh-password (I have not installed keys on the remote endpoint).

knife ssh 'name:ep1' uptime --ssh-password password

So probably an issue with key or password.  -VV is your friend.

Comment: thanks that really solved this issue, but if you a way not writing the password in clear text, please share

Comment: Had the same issue.. I was using a -i with key... but the file didn't exist and that was giving same error. Before trying this... will it be possible to try a normal ssh -i key user@host? if that fails it is solved

Comment: Had this strange output sending me into a rabbit hole today Lol ... Turned out I had a typo in the `knife[:identity_file]` value

Answer (score 2):

In order to resolve this issue, first check the client node and check whether root access is provided.
Check the file /etc/ssh/sshd_config file and change the permitrootaccess to Yes.
Stop ssh and the again start

or else use --sudo along with any username and password in the command

Answer (score 1):

I had this very same error; what I did to resolve it was simply add `-P` as part of the `knife ssh` command that I was running. `knife ssh` by default tries to use key-auth if it's not explicitly told to use password auth.

Sample of bad running command: `knife ssh "role:*" "uptime" -x <user>`

Sample of fixed running command: `knife ssh "role:*" "uptime" -x <user> -P`

Answer (score 1):

This problem is usually caused by not having the right private key PEM file added to your local ssh agent. Doing something like:

$ ssh-add

Comment: This was sort of the answer for me.  Typing ssh-add wasn't enough. I had to specify all the keys of all the machines being SSH'd into.  Once they were all loaded in to the keychain, the double user@foo@foo thing disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this command:

```
knife ssh 'name:node1.example.com' -P "redhat" chef-client
```

Here `node1.example.com` is the target machine. `-P` the password of root user.

Comment: Great answer; the password must still be entered, but at least it is not preserved in history (instead in the Enter you password: command). Still not sure why this issue exists as I can easily ssh into all boxes and set up chef-server correctly (or so I thought). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra search in your command. What you want is:

```
knife ssh 'name:chefnode' 'uptime'
```

Comment: no..if i dont state -a ipaddress.. it will use fqdn which i dont have any dns applied on. and you will still get something like:  "for user siegfried@ubuntu.gateway.2wire.net@ubuntu.gateway.2wire.net"

Comment: what is shown if you run 'knife show node chefnode -a ipaddress'?

Comment: siegfried@ubuntu:~/chef-repo$ knife node show chefnode -a ipaddress
chefnode:
  ipaddress: 192.168.1.73

Comment: I'm not sure why you are getting two ip addresses then. Do you have some sort of ssh alias config on your system that might be adding the extra information?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem. After re-running my knife command with the option -VV, I could see in the debug output that it was unable to load my ssh key.

```
could not load public key file `c:/Users/Carolyn/.ssh/id_rsa': Net::SSH::Exception (public key at c:/Users/Carolyn/.ssh/id_rsa.pub is not valid)
```

Turns out my private key was created by PuTTY and wasn't in the right format. The key header looked like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,DA9126F8AA3ED553
```

After I replaced my private and public key with keys generated using ssh-keygen, knife worked without problems. Now my private key header looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete ALL NODES IN YOUR CHEF, THAT DONT REALLY EXISTS (not active, chef cannot reach them etc.) and it would solve your problem. Really.

Answer (score 0):

Add your workstation's public key to target node's root .ssh/authorized_keys

Answer (score 0):

**For me the solution was to ensure that my local `ssh-agent` had both keys to the bastion host AND the target node**. Once that was the case, a command like this worked. In other words:

Given I am using a bastion host

And I have 2 distinct ssh key pairs; 1 to get from workstation to the bastion host and another to get from the bastion host into the target nodes

And the output of `ssh-agent -l` from my workstation is

`2048 SHA256:yyyyy /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
    2048 SHA256:zzzzz /Users/me/.ssh/internal-vpc-private-rsa-key (RSA)`

When I run a command like:

`knife ssh "$CHEF_SEARCH_QUERY" interactive \
  --config knife.rb \
  --ssh-gateway $JUMPBOX_IP \
  --ssh-user $SSH_USER \
  --attribute 'cloud.public_ipv4'`

Then N interactive ssh sessions are established with the target hosts

Answer (score 0):

Just get the right login credential for your client node. i fixed by adding knife ssh -i  "name:*" ""

Answer (score 0):

My issue ended up being the type of key I was using. I was using ed25519 but the version of Chef that I was using does not support ed25519. @krsyoung is absolutely correct that -VV is your friend.